# saving lapply results to the list over which function applied

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

In the spirit of "no question is too simple" , how do I save the output of an `lapply` function to the list on which it was applied. For e.g. I am doing

`lapply(listofdf, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", x[ ,18])))`

where x is data frame and `gsub` is applied to 18th column. I want to save the result to the 18th column in the listofdf itself. I've never worked with lists. with a data frame we would simply do 
`df$whatever <- function(df$whatever, .... )` . With a `list` how would this work?

Comment: It would be better if you show some small example datasets that have this anomaly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
listofdf <- lapply(listofdf, function(x){
                        x[,18] <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", x[ ,18])) 
                        #assign 18th column to the modified column 
                        x #return the dataframe
                       })
```

Comment: it starts printing all the operation and results in my console as the function is being performed instead of just saving quietly to the list element. Also, the result didn't save to the `listofdf` . scratches head - let me update my question.

Comment: @vagabond You could assign that to `listodf <- lapply(listofdf, ...)` so that it works quietly.

Comment: yep except, my results are varying. I am testing the output with : `lapply(listofdf, function(x) range(x[, "hour"]))` and I've applied the same function on a data frame which combines all the df in the list with `combineddf <- do.call(rbind, listofdf)`and then `combineddf$hour <- as.numeric(gsub(":\\d+", "", combineddf$hour))`.

Comment: @vagabond Are you saying that the range is different in both cases? In the combineddf, you have the `hour` from all the datasets, so I would assume that to be different rather than applying it on single datasets on each list element.

Comment: right, but that's not the problem. Some of the hour values are like  so "9:01", "8:01". the `gsub` removes them. In the data frame, range is from 0 to 23. But in the list, the range becomes from 0 to 9. I was inadvertently leaving out the `as.numeric` when using `lapply`. `combineddf$hour <- as.numeric(gsub(":\\d+", "", combineddf$hour))` vs. `listofdf <- lapply(listofdf, function(x) { x[ , "hour"] <- gsub(":\\d+", "", x[ ,"hour"]) 
                                           x })`

Comment: @vagabond Oh, okay. So, the range got confused by the character elements.